# Get latest version from solution and all its projects from command line

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I created a Visual Studio solution with a project called ProjectMain, and other three projects that where added from other locations (with the "add existing project")

If i try to get latest version from Visual Studio IDE it works fine (right click on Solution1, get latest version). This way ProjectMain, Project1, Project2 and Project3 are downloaded from TFS to their respective local paths, which is OK.

I need to do the same thing but using only one TFS command line sentence.

Something like this:

tf get $/TeamProject/Solution1

The solution file has information of every project that belongs to it, so I thing it's possible.

How can I do it with just one tfs get setence?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately visual studio does some magic there and dad the contents of the solution files and does gets accordingly.

The tf change does not naivety understand solutions.